# Play/pause button in Sonos

Tags: sonos

I have a Programmed Radio service, so my music containers are "programs". Every time the play/pause button is clicked in the Mac Controller (probably it also happens with other controllers though I haven't tried it yet), the application sends again the getMetadata function and discards the songs that were already in the queue waiting to be played. Is that the expected behaviour? How could we avoid it so the next songs to be played are those sent in the first place? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is the expected behavior.  Unfortunately there is not currently a way to prevent that from occurring.  However the currently playing track should still resume and complete normally.